# How to access to a specific taxonomy sublevel child

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I have a list of terms (with three levels) belonging to a taxonomy:

```
 -Area (Taxonomy)

 -- Zone (First Term level)

 ---  Subzone (Second Term level)

 ---- Town (Third Term level)
```

How can I only access to the second level of taxonomies from this list?. Is there any service method that can be used for this purpose (i.e: taxonomyService)?.

The reason of this question is that I want to obtain only this level of terms inside a widget driver and display it in the view.

Thanks!

Comment: You can inject the `ITaxonomyService`, it has a method `GetChildren(TermPart term)`